# SQL Server String manipulation column to new column

Tags: sql-server

Need to create new column from the existing column with string manipulation on the fly

Existing stored string in the column is `nvarchar`

Existing column string example value 0001134564444

Need, the first three positions '000' to become 'AB' (there is a good number of variations)

the following 11 shall be 1 (there are eight variations results (1 to 8))

the following 3456 shall take the last two characters 56

the last 4444 shall not change.

The new string should then be AB5614444

Now need this done in SQL server,...

have tried `with`, `substring`, `stuff`, `replace`, `charindex`
Have reached the point...never too late to give up, this is my last chance.

Oracle version,

```
select column NewColumn, decode(substr(column, 1,3),'000','AB', '010', 'BC' ...)||substr(column,8,2)
||substr(column,5,1)||substr(column,10,5) NewStringColumn from table
```

getting absolutely nowhere with SQL server for this task, oracle remains no longer an option.
any help is appreciated,

Comment: Please add sample input and output data.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be AB1564444?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select
  case substring(c, 1, 3) when '000' then 'AB' when '010' then 'BC' ... end
  +
  case substring(c, 4, 2) when '11' then '1' ... end
  +
  substring(c, 8, 6)
```

```sql
with first_mapping as (
  select k, v
  from (values
    ('000', 'AB'),
    ('010', 'BC'),
    ...
  ) v(k, v)
),
second_mapping as (
  select k, v
  from (values
    ('11', '1'),
    ...
  ) v(k, v)
)
select
  (select v from first_mapping where k = substring(c, 1, 3))
  +
  (select v from second_mapping where k = substring(c, 4, 2))
  +
  substring(c, 8, 6)
```